# htaccess: move traffic to www subdomain, so long as not cdn

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have this in my .htaccess to move all traffic to www

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The issue is it is also moving my cdn traffic as well; what I need it to do is not move to WWW if is:
    cdn.example.com
    cdn1.example.com
    cdn2.example.com
    cdn3.example.com
    cdn4.example.com

any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

You can do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www|cdn|cdn1|cdn2)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This can be optimised a bit into:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www|cdn[12]?)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I did not test this, so hope it helps.